# How to migrate RethinkDb into MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb, database-migration, rethinkdb

My application is using RethinkDb. Everything is running fine, but a new required needs to migrate the db into MongoDb.

Is this possible? How do I migrate the tables/collections, data, indexes, etc?
How about blob types, auto increments. ids?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> Is this possible? How do I migrate the tables/collections, data, indexes, etc?

One way to migrate data from RethinkDB to MongoDB is to export data from RethinkDB using [rethinkdb dump](https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/backup/) command, and then use [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/)  to import into MongoDB. For *example*:

```
rethinkdb dump -e dbname.tableName
```

This would generate an archive file:

```
rethinkdb_dump_<datetime>.tar.gz
```

After uncompressing the archive file, you can then use `mongoimport` as below:

```
mongoimport --jsonArray --db dbName --collection tableName ./rethinkdb_dump_<datetime>/dbName/tableName.json
```

Unfortunately for the indexes, the format between RethinkDB and MongoDB is quite different. The indexes are stored within the same archived file:

```
./rethinkdb_dump_<datetime>/dbName/tableName.info
```

Although you can still write a Python script to read the `info` file, and use [MongoDB Python driver (PyMongo)](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/) to create the indexes in MongoDB. See also [create_indexes()](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.create_indexes) method for more information.

One of the reasons in suggesting to use Python, is because RethinkDB also has a [Client Python driver](https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/cookbook/python/). So technically, you can also skip the export stage and write a script to connect your RethinkDB to MongoDB.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was thinking to use rethinkdb dump to export it into JSON... then have mongoimport to import the JSON file... but with this, I think I will have to manually recreate the index. Yeah, I believe using python script would be a great help. Thanks so much :)

Comment: Is it possible to migrate from mongodb to rethinkdb? Just like the other way around?